# Queries caching or

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, caching

I am using MYSql database and Entity Framework as an ORM to it.
I have two tables:
table A and table B. Table A has a field which is a foreign key on some field from table B.
And the constraints to this key are: Update:Restrict, Delete:Restrict
So the situation:

- when I try to delete a record from table B everything works fine
- when I try to delete a record from table B and this record is referenced by another record from table A it does nothing and it is expected ofc.
- when I try to delete a record from table B, which is referenced, it does nothing but if I after this try to delete a record from table A which was referencing that record from table B it appears that both records are deleted. But only the record from table A should be deleted.

So I assume that there is some kind of caching which caches the unsuccessfull query and tries to execute it when possible.

In some time I`ll try to post some pictures if my words are very fuzzy =)

Ah, and the question: can anyone clear this situation?)

Comment: Please give a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) of the code that's causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue.
No caching or such things =)
Just entity object which I tried to delete was marked with EntityState.Deleted and despite the exception throwed the state wasn`t rollbacked.